# Ubuntu 12.04 Lenovo X61T, how to assign display buttons as shortcuts? Bug?

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys, lenovo, button

I got some problems to get display buttons to work.

I'm trying to assign functions (settings->keyboard->shortcuts) to the display buttons on my Lenovo X61 Tablet Notebook. The buttons are:
- Change screen orientation - recognized as 'screensaver'
- Toolbox - recognized as 'touchpad toggle'
(same functions as with Fn-Key available?)

If I assign them to non-custom shortcuts - everything is all right, but when I do this with custom shortcuts, e.g. running a script, they behave as normal not assigned buttons(starting the screensaver or locking the touchpad).

Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could override metacity keybinding, like in this hint:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/assign-custom-shortcut-keys-on-ubuntu-linux/

So instead of using custom shortcuts in (settings->keyboard->shortcuts) you would edit them via gconf-editor and add them as a custom commands in "apps\metacity\keybinding_commands"